# React Router: how to navigate programatically outside of a component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to navigate to path `/hello` and try the following:

```js
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'
browserHistory.push('/hello')
```

But it only changes the browser's URL to `/hello` without actually navigating to that page. Inside of a component, this method works:

```js
this.props.history.push('/hello')
```

This is how I set up my router:

```js
// Configure history for react-router
const browserHistory = useRouterHistory(createBrowserHistory)({
  basename: __BASENAME__
})

// Create redux store and sync with react-router-redux. We have installed the
// react-router-redux reducer under the key "router" in src/routes/index.js,
// so we need to provide a custom `selectLocationState` to inform
// react-router-redux of its location.
const initialState = window.__INITIAL_STATE__
const store = configureStore(initialState, browserHistory)
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store, {
  selectLocationState: (state) => state.router
})

// Now that we have the Redux store, we can create our routes. We provide
// the store to the route definitions so that routes have access to it for
// hooks such as `onEnter`.
const routes = makeRoutes(store)

// Now that redux and react-router have been configured, we can render the
// React application to the DOM!
ReactDOM.render(
  <Root history={history} routes={routes} store={store} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

References:

1. https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#programmatic-navigation
2. https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/issues/1081

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I setup the `browserHistory`, I store it inside a global namespace:

```
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store, {
  selectLocationState: (state) => state.router
})
window.routerHistory = history
```

Then I can navigate outside of a component like below:

```
window.routerHistory.push('/')
```